# vuejs beforeDestory hook in wrapper component

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuex, wrapper

I'm making a wrapper component and have to clear the vuex when I close the component.
I've registered this component in a menu, and parent component is default main page(init page when page is loaded).

So basically, I have to get the data from main component(which is Map(geo json) and displays markers) to pass down(i'm using vuex to share data) the data to grand-child component which is a wrapper component(leaflet-draw) to display maker(main component, grand parent component) information at grand-child component(menu)

But whenever I reopen the grand-child component, it keeps add up existing data. so let say there's 10 data in main component, and then whenever I open it, it just keep adds data cuz it's a wrapper component, and I have to use mounted() hook to get all data info.

so mounted() hook is called everytime I open it, but when beforeDestroy() is called, mounted() hook doesn't work anymore...

Could you please tell me how to use beforeDestory() or destroyed() hook correctly for the wrapper component...?

Many thanks.

It's over 8000 lines so let me know if you need a test case. I will add the github link.

Answer (score 0):

I would add it as a comment but it says that i need 50 rep anyway; as far as i understood you are fetching the data when your wrapper component mounts so; maybe you should write sth like:
 `if state is populated empty the state then fetch the new data` 
 in the function where you fetch the data which should be in your actions.